# Ordenação de Matriz com Troca de Valores

Tags: javascript, array, matriz, for, classificação

Boa Tarde! Montei uma matriz que recebe 9 registros de uma única variável e os valores são exibidos na tela do usuário. Porém, ao tentar colocar esta matriz em ordem crescente, eu tentei utilizar o método da troca de valores, só que na hora de aplicá-lo a este algoritmo, os três ultimos valores digitados via teclado foram repetidos três vezes:

```js
var linha = Array(3,3);
var x, y, troca;
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
      linha[x,y] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o "+[y+1]+"º número da "+[x+1]+"º coluna"));
  }
}
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    if (linha[x] < linha[y]){
      troca = linha[x];
      linha[x] = linha[y];
      linha[y] = troca;
    }
  }
}
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    document.write(linha[x,y]+"&nbsp&nbsp");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

**Pergunta:** Qual método seria mais simples e lógico para ordenar os 9 números digitados pelo usuário em ordem crescente neste problema apresentado?
[image: Esta figura apresenta o resultado que eu esperava aparecer na tela.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que, o comando "Array(3,3)" não cria uma matriz de 9 posições e sim, uma matriz com apenas duas posições, sendo o índice 0 => 3 e o índice 1 => 3. No javascript, quando utilizar a função Array, cada elemento passado por "," é considerado um item. Para resolvermos isto, você fará da seguinte forma:

```js
// Função de comparação numérica básica, será utilizada
// para testar os números e saber qual é maior que qual
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

// Criar um Quadrado de quantos lados?
// Criei esta variável para caso queira aumentar as posições,
// basta informar aqui
var lados = 3;

// Será criado um array com 'n lados, depende da variável' mas, vazios.
var linha = new Array(lados * lados);

var x, y, troca;
for (x = 0; x < lados; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y < lados; y++) {
      // Utilizando o x * lados, vamos ter as seguintes posições
      // x = 0 e y = 0 === 0 - Posição 1 do Array
      // x = 0 e y = 1 === 1 - Posição 2 do Array
      // x = 0 e y = 2 === 2 - Posição 3 do Array
      // x = 1 e y = 0 === 3 - Posição 4 do Array
      // x = 1 e y = 1 === 4 - Posição 5 do Array
      // x = 1 e y = 2 === 5 - Posição 6 do Array
      // x = 2 e y = 0 === 6 - Posição 7 do Array
      // x = 2 e y = 1 === 7 - Posição 8 do Array
      // x = 2 e y = 2 === 8 - Posição 9 do Array       
      linha[(x * lados) + y] = parseInt(prompt("Digite o "+[y+1]+"º número da "+[x+1]+"º coluna"));
  }
}

// Removido esta parte, basta utilizar o comando SORT do Array passando uma função para ordenar.
// for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
//   for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
//     if (linha[x] < linha[y]){
//       troca = linha[x];
//       linha[x] = linha[y];
//       linha[y] = troca;
//     }
//   }
// }

// Vai ordenar os itens do array, passando como parâmetro a função que criamos
linha = linha.sort(sortNumber)

for (x = 0; x < lados; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y < lados; y++) {
    // Alterado a forma como acessar o índice do array.
    // Ficou x * lados + y para acessar de forma correta as posições
    document.write(linha[(x * lados) + y]+"&nbsp&nbsp");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @BrunoRigolon pela ajuda e colaboração. Esse era um desafio que tinha que fazer e não estava conseguindo terminá-lo e sua contribuição me ajudou a entendê-lo mais. :-)